# request.getRemoteUser returns null after a certain time?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, jdbcrealm

I have a web application with Java Tomcat JSP and for the login-Authentification.
I use Realm-Technology.

I have the problem that the `request.getRemoteUser` returns null after a certain time (maybe half a hour). 
And the result that in the database it will be add `null` for the creator.

Comment: That would indicate that the session has timed out.

Comment: Are you storing the request somewhere and accessing it after 30 mins.

Answer (score 1):

Because , of session is expires after 30 minutes that's why it is giving null value.
you can also increase the session Time out value from your web.xml file.
by default it is 30 min.